# Javascript: sorting numbers ending with a zero not working (4.0 5.0 etc..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I use the following javascript to get the ranking from the current div within a list of div's based on it's data-attribute data-rating, when the current number is 3.0, 4.0 or 5.0 (ending with a zero) it won't work and gives 0 instead of the actual ranking, what am I doing wrong here?

```
var count = $.inArray($("[data-rating]").filter(".current").data("rating"), $.map($("[data-rating]"), function(el, i) {
         return Number(el.attributes["data-rating"].value)
        }).sort(function(b, a) {
         return a - b
        }));

$(".rating").html(count + 1);
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="foo" data-rating="5.0"></div>
<div class="foo" data-rating="4.8"></div>
<div class="foo current" data-rating="4.0"></div>
<div class="foo" data-rating="4.3"></div>
<div class="foo" data-rating="3.7"></div>
<div class="foo" data-rating="4.3"></div>

<div class="rating"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `data-reviews` in one place in your JS, but your HTML uses `data-rating`?

Comment: suggest not trying to piece together so many parts into one , create variables to make the logic easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first argument to `$.inArray()` to:

```
Number($("[data-rating]").filter(".current").attr("data-rating"))
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fsmtc0z/)

The problem stems from the use of the `.data()` method. You are relying on that method to convert the `data-rating` attribute value to a `number`, but it does not perform the conversion for values like `"4.0"`. Instead, `.data()` returns a `string` for those values. That means in those cases you are passing a `string` as the first argument to the `$.inArray()` method, which results in it not finding the value in the array.

If you look at [the documentation for `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), it states:

> A value is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the
>   value's representation.

Therefore, `.data()` does not convert `"4.0"` to a `number` because it would get converted to just `4`.

Because of these kinds of issues, I was once advised to use `.data(key)` to get a value only if the value was set with `.data(key, value)`, and to use `.attr(name)` if the value was set using an HTML5 `data-*` attribute (and to perform explicit type conversion). I consider it to be good advice.

Answer (score 1):

So I have untangled your code a little bit to make it easier to go through. The sorting works fine:

```
var sorted = $.map($("[data-rating]"), function(el, i) {
     return Number(el.attributes["data-rating"].value)
    }).sort(function(b, a) {
     return a - b
    });
// [5, 4.8, 4.3, 4.3, 4, 3.7]
```

Then you take the rating of `.current` element, which returns `"4.0"`

```
var current = $("[data-rating]").filter(".current").data("rating");
```

And pass it to `$.inArray()`:

```
 var count = $.inArray( current, sorted);
```

That `inArray` returns `-1` because it can't find the string "4.0" in an array of numbers. For some reason `$.inArray( current, Number(sorted))` doesn't work either.

If you use `parseFloat` instead of `Number` both in`.map` and `.inArray` it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/gqkgetLk/2/

BTW What's the reason for `sort`? If you want to print the rating of an element with the class `.current` you could just use

```
$(".rating").html( $('[data-rating].current').data('rating') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gqkgetLk/1/

Comment: I use sort, because I am trying to get the ranking relative to the other values not the rating itself.

Comment: @coder oh, OK. then you may need to watch out for duplicate ratings i.e. if four items have a rating of 5 and one item is rated 4, it may be said it is fifth or second in the ranking depending on your desired result.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that, currently it works fine, and says it is the 5th rating in that case, which seems correct.